# Join sub queries in PL-SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I know this is really basic, but I'm stuck. I'm unable to select specific columns from a join of sub queries. For example -

This works -

```
select * from
(subquery) x
left join
(subquery) y
on x.id = y.id
```

This also works -

```
select x.id from
(subquery) x
left join
(subquery) y
on x.id = y.id
```

This works as well -

```
select y.id from
(subquery) x
left join
(subquery) y
on x.id = y.id
```

This does **NOT** work -

```
select x.id, y.id from
(subquery) x
left join
(subquery) y
on x.id = y.id
```

What am I missing in the last query? Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: This should work just as well. Except for the case where you need unique column names, e.g. when making this another query's subquery. Use alias names then: `select x.id as x_id, y.id as y_id from ...`.

Comment: What does "NOT work" mean ? Error message ? No records ?